# How can I create a list from a JSON that many parents with different names?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

Hello I have a JSON list called "Diseases.json
it's formatted like this:

```
{
"Hypertensive disease": [
    "Pain chest",
    "Shortness of breath",
    "Dizziness",
    "Asthenia",
    "Fall",
    "Syncope",
    "Vertigo",
    "Sweat",
    "Sweating increased",
    "Palpitation",
    "Nausea",
    "Angina pectoris",
    "Pressure chest"
],
"Coronavirus disease 2019": [
    "Fever",
    "Dry cough",
    "Fatigue",
    "Pain",
    "Throat sore",
    "Diarrhea",
    "Headache",
    "Loss of taste or smell",
    "Out of breath",
    "Pain chest",
    "Pressure chest"
],
"Diabetes": [
    "Polyuria",
    "Polydypsia",
    "Shortness of breath",
    "Pain chest",
    "Asthenia",
    "Nausea",
    "Orthopnea",
    "Rale",
    "Sweat",
    "Sweating increased",
    "Unresponsiveness",
    "Mental status changes",
    "Vertigo",
    "Vomiting",
    "Labored breathing"
],
"Depression mental": [
    "Feeling suicidal",
    "Suicidal",
    "Hallucinations auditory",
    "Feeling hopeless",
    "Weepiness",
    "Sleeplessness",
    "Motor retardation",
    "Irritable mood",
    "Blackout",
    "Mood depressed",
    "Hallucinations visual",
    "Worry",
    "Agitation",
    "Tremor",
    "Intoxication",
    "Verbal auditory hallucinations",
    "Energy increased",
    "Difficulty",
    "Nightmare",
    "Unable to concentrate",
    "Homelessness"
], }
```

I want this JSON list to be a list in flutter where could get data from their parents.
I tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:diagnose_app/check_symptoms.dart';

import 'diseaseNames.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'test.dart';

class Results extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  const Results({required this.list});

  @override
  State<Results> createState() => _ResultsState();
}

class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
  List symptoms = [];
  List diseases = [];

  //var level = List.generate(147, (index) => 0);

  Future<dynamic> readJson() async {
    final String response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/Diseases.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    //print(data);

    setState(() {
      // this doesn't work
      diseases = data;
    });
    return data;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    readJson();
    //print(symptoms);
    symptoms = widget.list;
    symptoms.toString();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know I'm approching the data parsing in a wrong way but I looked out all over internet for getting data from json file that contains multiple parents with different names then putting them in one list.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type should be list. It should be a `Map<String, List<String>>` where the `key` is the the parent name and the `value` is a list of the symptoms. You could then easily access each parent by name without without a convoluted list. JSON by its very nature resembles a `Map<>`. There are many libraries that do this easily (jackson, GSON, etc.).